# How to link section title if too long and truncated using nameref command?

Tags: sectioning, hyperref

I use `\nameref` command in order to link section title. But if section title is too long and truncated it will not linked.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\title{Sample File}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Comparison with existing hierarchical decomposition methods}
\label{sec1}

This is a simple text. This is a simple text. This is a simple text. This is a simple      text. This is a simple text. This is a simple text. This is a simple text. This is a simple text. This is a simple text. This is a simple text~\nameref{sec1}. This is a simple text. This is a simple text.
```

This is a simple text.I use `\nameref` command in order to link section title. But if section title is too long and truncated it will not linked.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\title{Sample File}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Comparison with existing hierarchical decomposition methods}
\label{sec1}

This is a simple text. This is a simple text. This is a simple text. This
is a simple text. This is a simple text. This is a simple text. This is a
simple text. This is a simple text. This is a simple text. This is a
simple text~\nameref{sec1}. This is a simple text. This is a simple text.
This is a simple text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of `\section`, i.e.

```
\section[short]{Long tittle}
\label{sec:ref}
```

In this way `\nameref{sec:ref}` will use the short title.

Comment: There's a typo in your answer, as the ``\nameref`` command that you give starts with a square bracket and ends with a curly bracket. Unfortunately I cannot edit it myself, because the stackexchange system says that I have to change a minimum of 6 characters. Maybe you as the author can change it anyway.

Comment: @BenediktBauer Fixed